# How do I recursively sum digits of a number until I'm left with only one digit using mathematical expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, recursion

My goal is to be able to prove by induction that if I recursively sum the digits of a number $n$ (a natural number) until I am left with only one digit which is a member of $\{0, 3, 6, 9\}$ then $n$ is divisible by $3$.

Since this is supposed to be written recursively I wrote up a function 
$S(n) = \sum_{i=0}^k n_i + S(n)$ however I don't know how to stop it if it reaches one digit. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you already know how to show that a positive integer and its [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) have the same remainder when divided by 9?

Comment: Could you show one simple example?

Comment: Subtracting S(n) from both sides of the equation you gave shows the sum of the digits is zero.